# Ruby pop an element from a hash table?

Tags: ruby

I am looking at http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html and there does not appear to be a `pop` method? I think I am missing something though...

```
if (x = d['a']) != nil
  d.delete('a') 
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is there really no better way to `pop` an item from a Hash? Is there a reason I shouldn't worry about it? (I'm not familiar with how Ruby is compiled, so I don't know if the lack of a singular method is a big deal like it would be in Python).

Comment: You are referring to a `pop()` method which conventionally implies removing (and returning) the last element from a collection. You example code doesn't appear to be doing that though. What action specifically do you want to take?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski My code does exactly what `pop` does. You are welcome to try it.

Comment: @user3467349 Ok - your code does what _python's `pop`_ does, not what Ruby's `Array#pop` does, or what `pop()` does in typical ordered structures, which is to pop the top element off a stack. The Ruby name for what Python does there is `Hash#delete`.

Comment: I see... the `delete` method returns the value. That's not very intuitive. But I guess that answers my question.

Comment: Yep, it's kind of a misnomer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you know the key, just use delete directly
if the hash doesn't contain the key, you will get nil back, otherwise you will get whatever was stored there

from the doc you linked to:

```
h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
h.delete("a")                              #=> 100
h.delete("z")                              #=> nil
h.delete("z") { |el| "#{el} not found" }   #=> "z not found"
```

There is also shift which deletes and returns a key-value pair:

```
hsh = Hash.new

hsh['bb'] = 42
hsh['aa'] = 23
hsh['cc'] = 65

p hsh.shift

=> ["bb", 42]
```

As can be seen, the order of a hash is the order of insertion, not the key or value. From the doc

> Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted.

Comment: Your code in the question does exactly the same as d.delete('a') so I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes I hadn't realized `delete` returned a value.

Comment: It's not completely obvious from the method name. There is also shift which behaves sort of like pop on an array where it deletes and returns a key-value pair

Comment: What's the behaviour like for `shift` and `first` does it just return the first `key-val` pair it comes across or are the hash-tables actually ordered in some way?

Comment: The short answer is that hashes behaves like arrays in the sense that first/shift returns the element that was first inserted, but writing code that depends on it is bad. The order of hashes is an implementation detail.

Your code becomes less clear and it might even behave differently in some Ruby implementations. If you want items in a certain order then use an array or sort them explicitly. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31425274/813125 for more details.