# Ruby GraphQL: How to order arguments in an option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

I am using SearchObject with GraphQL in Ruby on Rails and created an option called :order_by

```
option :order_by, type: LinksOrderBy, with: :apply_order_by
```

The type LinksOrderBy is defined by this:

```
class LinksOrderBy < ::Types::BaseInputObject
  argument :created_at, AscDescEnum, required: false
  argument :description, AscDescEnum, required: false
  argument :id, AscDescEnum, required: false
  argument :updated_at, AscDescEnum, required: false
  argument :url, AscDescEnum, required: false
end
```

But when I try something like this in GraphQL query:

```
{allLinks(order_by:{id: asc, description: desc}) {
    id
    description
}}
```

I don't get it in the right order:

```
def apply_order_by(scope, value)
  scope.order(value.arguments.to_h.map{|k, v| k + ' ' + v}.join(', ')) # "description desc, id asc"
end
```

As you can see the right order should be **"id, description"**, not **"description, id"**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ruby Hash instances are not ordered (see [Is order of a Ruby hash literal guaranteed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418673/is-order-of-a-ruby-hash-literal-guaranteed))

---

To leverage the optional multi sorting options in GraphQL input types, I usually use the following structure:

- 1 enum to contain all filterable/sortable/searchable field of a resource (ex: `UserField`)
- 1 enum to contain the 2 sort directions (`asc` and `desc`)
- 1 field accepting an optional list of `{ field: UserField!, sortDir: SortDir! }` inputs.

This then enables the API consumers to simply do queries like:

```
allUsers(sort_by: [{field: username, sortDir: desc}, {field: id, sortDir: asc}]) {
  # ...
}
```

And this pattern can be easily re-used for searching and filtering:

```
allUsers(search: [{field: username, comparator: like, value: 'bob'}]) {}
allUsers(search: [{field: age, comparator: greater_than, value: '22'}]) {} # type casting is done server-side
allUsers(search: [{field: username, comparator: equal, value: 'bob'}]) {} # equivalent of filtering
```

---

Eventually, with further deeper work you can allow complex `and`/`or` for the input:

```
allUsers(
  search: [
    {
      left: {field: username, comparator: like, value: 'bob'}
      operator: and
      right: {field: dateOfBirth, comparator: geater_than, value: '2001-01-01'}
    }
  ]
)
```

Disclaimer: the last example above is one of the many things I want to implement in my GQL API but I haven't had the time to think it through yet, it's just a draft

Comment: loved the approach

Comment: I used your approach to create a gem. gem 'graphql_scaffold'. What do you think about it?

Comment: That's a good idea, let me know if you need help implementing it @ArthurFelipe

Comment: Fell free to fork and add anything you think would be better. It is still at the begining... Thank you! https://github.com/arthurmolina/graphql_scaffold

Comment: I'm totally new to graphql, could you share a demo/github link to understand how u extended the GraphQL-Ruby Type Definition System and in which file you added the field to all queries?