# Why can't I access contents of flash when it's a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-hash

According to the [Flash documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html), I should be able to pass strings, arrays or hashes through Flash. Strings and arrays work fine but hashes aren't working.

Here's a stripped down (but still failing) version of my code:

#### Flash messages partial

```
# views/layouts/flash_messages.html.haml

- flash.each do |type, content|
  - message = content if content.class == String
  - message, detail = content if content.class == Array
  - message, detail = content[:message], content[:detail] if content.class == Hash
  - if message || detail
    .alert
      %h3= message if message.present?
      %p= detail if detail.present?
```

#### Home controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def test_string
    redirect_to root_url, alert: 'Plain string works'
  end

  def test_array
    redirect_to root_url, alert: ['Array works', 'Tested with 0, 1, 2 or more items without problems']
  end

  def test_hash
    redirect_to root_url, alert: {message: 'Hash not working :(', detail: 'Even though I think it should'}
  end
end
```

The problem seems to be with the assignment line in the case of the hash, the keys are present but `method` and `detail` always end up nil for hashes. But when I try the same code in the console it works fine...

#### IRB

```rb
irb> content = { message: 'This hash works...', detail: '...as expected' }
=> {:message=>"This hash works...", :detail=>"...as expected"}
irb> message, detail = content[:message], content[:detail] if content.class == Hash
=> [ 'This hash works...', '...as expected' ]
irb> message
=> 'This hash works...'
irb> detail
=> '...as expected'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closer inspection revealed that, while the keys were indeed set, they'd been converted from symbols to strings.

To fix this I had to change line 4 of the controller from symbols to strings:

```rb
- message, detail = content[:message], content[:detail] if content.class == Hash
- message, detail = content['message'], content['detail'] if content.class == Hash
```

If I [understand correctly](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22796#issuecomment-167355190), this is a result of flashes being stored in the session and the session object being stored in cookies as JSON objects. JSON doesn't support symbolised keys.

As an experiment I tried setting matching string and symbol keys. If you try doing both in one assignment, Ruby takes the first key and the second value (with a warning):

```rb
irb> content = { message: 'Symbol key first', 'message': 'String key second' }
=> warning: key :message is duplicated and overwritten on line X
=> {:message=>"String key second"}
```

But if you deliberately duplicate the keys in a hash passed to flash, whichever one is defined last "wins" (in my limited testing, but it makes sense given hashes are [most likely iterated in insertion order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31425274/145725)):

```rb
symbol_first = {}
symbol_first[:message] = 'Symbol wins'
symbol_first['message'] = 'String wins'
flash[:alert] = symbol_first # 'String wins' is displayed

string_first = {}
string_first['message'] = 'String wins'
string_first[:message] = 'Symbol wins'
flash[:alert] = string_first # 'Symbol wins' is displayed
```